# Optional Of Nullable Executes orElse when map returns null

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I have written a simple snippet

```
String aa = "aa";
String aaa = null;

String result = Optional.ofNullable(aa)
                        .map(s -> aaa)
                        .orElse("bb");

System.out.println(result);
```

`orElse` shall be executed when `aa` is null. But it is getting executed when `map` returns null as well.

My understanding is that `orElse` will be executed only `aa` is null. But will it be executed even when map return null?

Comment: This snippet prints "bb". Can you elaborate on what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Mureinik. The orElse is executed only when aa is null. Or it will get executed even when .map return null

Comment: Or the other question, then to answer for you would be, what do you want to do is `aaa` is `null`? Optional cannot return `null` for sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My understanding is that orElse will be executed only aa is null. But
>   will it be executed even when map return null?

That's better explained by the implementation of the [`Optional.map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) function itself :

```
//         return type                 function to map
public <U> Optional<U> map(Function<? super T, ? extends U> mapper) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(mapper); // null check 
    if (!isPresent()) {
        return empty();    // could be true when 'aa' is null in your case
    } else {
        return Optional.ofNullable(mapper.apply(value)); // using Optional.ofNullable itself
    }
 }
```

Hence, if on applying the `mapper` i.e. in your case `s -> aaa` returns `null`, the `map` operation would return `Optional.empty` followed by `orElse` branching.

Comment: Thank you. I edited the question if aa is not null but aaa is null, still it would call orElse

Comment: @Patan That's what I added the last two lines for. In your case, `map` has a function that returns `null` on applying and hence further an `Optional.empty` taking you to `orElse` branch.

Comment: @nullpointer the implementation is not the source o the truth btw, only the doc is; the implementation is free to change at any point in time...

Comment: @Eugene Was actually thinking about sharing it or not.. and then I decided to inline comments to actually correlate to the documentation and the OP's use case. Nevertheless, I agree while the implementation can change the documentation should be considered the source of truth and hence kept it linked too.

Answer (score 3):

I have to disagree with the accepted answer to look at the implementation, only the documentation is the source of the truth here. And in your case this is rather simple, you are doing (which basically maps to `null`)

```
.map(s -> aaa)
```

And the doc says:

> If a value is present, apply the provided mapping function to it, **and if the result is non-null**, return an Optional describing the result.  Otherwise return an empty Optional.

In your case the result of the `s -> aaa` lambda in the `map` operation is null, thus the part  *Otherwise return an empty Optional* applies, thus the result of `orElse` is what you see.

Comment: Accepted answer is correct. And the documentation is also correct. An `Optional.ofNullable(null)` **is** an empty `Optional`.

Comment: The result of the lambda is null (not the map operation), but I see your point. Will edit an remove the downvote (although I still believe it is useful to look at the implementation).

Comment: @TonytheTech I get your point with the edit. removing my comments now.